# iOS: Archiving NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, archiving, nscoder

I've Googled and searched SO for this with no straightforward results. It seems I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the following from Apple's documentation:

> An archive can store an arbitrarily complex object graph. The archive
>   preserves the identity of every object in the graph and all the
>   relationships it has with all the other objects in the graph. When
>   unarchived, the rebuilt object graph should, with few exceptions, be
>   an exact copy of the original object graph.

Assume that I have an `NSMutableArray` that is a collection of `Person` objects. Each `Person` object implements `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder`. Further, any given `Person` may have an `NSMutableArray` of objects (similarly coding-compliant) of `Task`.

My understanding is that there is a way to archive, thus triggering a cascading serialization of arbitrary depth, depending on implementation of the coding protocol. So in my view controller, I have a `willEnterBackground` that does:

```
data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.people];
// persist to NSUserDefaults
```

and I have a `viewDidLoad` that does:

```
// read from NSUserDefaults
self.people = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

This all happens, but two things:

1. The `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder` in the objects contained by the `people` array are never called.
2. Unsurprisingly, the result is that `self.people` is an NSMutableArray of size 0. Surprisingly, the data that is unarchived is 252 bytes long, which looks about right.

Suggestions? Hints?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you implemented those 2 methods, did you declare your Person class to be in the protocol ?